# Where should I locate a water pressure regulator in my townhouse?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

What locations should I look in to find the water pressure regulator for my home?

It is a townhouse in NY state, with crawlspace. My section is 8 units connected together.

So far I’ve found about 5-6 pipes traversing my crawlspace between units. One pipe  enters into my crawlspace and promptly makes a turn towards the rear of my unit for the furnace room on my first floor.

I believe this is my main line and there is a shutoff in the furnace room for the whole unit.

I have an issue with a shower that goes all hot or cold as you turn the handle; it makes a banging/clunking sound when the water goes all hot or cold. Moen 1222 cartridge. Plumber felt the water pressure was too high; told me to call him back when I located the regulator.

Comment: The plumber should be able to check the water pressure at any sillcock that has a hose bib or you can pick one up at any hardware store.

Comment: My comment above was about picking up a water pressure gauge that can be attached to a hose bib - about $10. My guess is that the cartridge is faulty. You usually get banging in the pipes as the cartridge gets corroded with scale.

Comment: Hmm, I’ve actually replaced it about once a year and it seems to resolve; when i pull it out the old cartridge looks just like the new one though, no visible problems

Comment: The regulator may be located on the main incoming pipe.

Comment: Or there may be no pressure regulator depending on the age of the units...I would search for the main water shutoff box to your building, which is probably outside near the street.